# Noether normalisation $A=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(f)$ where $f=(x-a)y^2-(x-b)$ find a transcendence element

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

Noether normalisation $A=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(f)$ where $f=(x-a)y^2-(x-a)$ $a , b  \in \mathbb{C}$ find  $z \in A$.  transcendence over $\mathbb{C}$ such that $A$ is integral over  $\mathbb{C}[z]$

any suggestions ?

Comment: You may assume $a=0$. What have you tried so far? The proof of Noether N. is constructive.

Comment: What are your own thoughts on the question?

Comment: I don't think that this question should be closed (it has one close vote). The OP is looking for suggestions, not for answers. So I see no problem with leaving this question open.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the canonical solution, maybe someone else has a more elegant solution, but until then let 
$$z=y^2-(x-a)$$

then 
$$z^2=y^4-2(x-a)y^2+(x-a)^2$$ and on multiplying by $(x-a)^2$ we have

$$(x-a)^2z^2=(x-b)^4-2(x-a)(x-b)^2+(x-a)^4$$ which is easily seen to be a monic polynomial in $x$. So $x$ is integral over $A[z]$.
If we now note that $x=y^2-z+a$ and substitute in the above equation we get a monic polynomial for $y$, and $y$ is also integral.

This choice of $z$ follows from one proof of the Noether Normalization theorem.